# How to pick gems from a specific directory

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I forked a gem I use a lot in order to code some enhancements on it. I want it to be installed in a subfolder called ~/codebase/ruby, where I keep all my Ruby projects, arranged in subdirectories.

To do that, I built and installed the gem with the following commands:

```
gem build my_gem.gemspec
gem install mygem-x.x.gem -i./mygem
```

`mygem` is installed in `~/codebase/ruby/mygem`. I can't get my client code (which is in another directory) to grab `mygem` from there.

I've tried all of the following without success:

- Running ruby with argument `-I<path_to_mygem>.`
- Adding `<path_to_mygem>` to `PATH`.
- Putting `:gempath: <path_to_mygem>` into `~/.gemrc`.

I know I could put the gem in `~/.gem/ruby/<version>` (since it appears in `gem env`) and that would probably work, but that would break my existing directory structure of Ruby code, forcing me to code in a different directory only for `mygem`, which is something I want to avoid unless it's the only option.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you are using Bundler to load the required gems.  Then you just specify the path to the gem file in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'my_gem', :path => '~/codebase/ruby/mygem'
```